# How can I properly serialize wikidata SPARQL queries answers?

Tags: python, sparql, wikidata, sparqlwrapper

I have the following  example of querying wikidata via Python's SPARQLWrapper:

```
import rdflib, urllib
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON, XML, TURTLE, RDF, N3 
from rdflib import Graph, Namespace, URIRef, RDF#, RDFS, Literal    

def graph_full(uri, f)
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper('https://query.wikidata.org/sparql')
    sparql.setQuery('''
    PREFIX entity: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>

    SELECT ?predicate ?object WHERE {
        <'''+urllib.unquote(uri).encode("utf8")+'''> ?predicate ?object .
    } LIMIT 100
    ''')

    sparql.setReturnFormat(N3)
    results = sparql.query().convert()
    #print results.serialize()

    print type(results)
    g = Graph()
    g.parse(results)
    print g 
    #g.serialize(f, format="n3")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph_full("entity:Q76", "wikidata/output.nt")
```

I want to serialize the result of the SPARQL query and save it to a file. This seems to always throw the following error:

```
Exception: Unexpected type '<type 'instance'>' for source    '<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x7fa11e3715a8>'
```

Using similar code against DBpedia SPARQL endpoints throws no erros.

Comment: In what format do you expect to save the results? What you get with a SPARQL select query are SPARQL results, not a graph, so trying to parse them with Graph.parse will not work. If you set the format to JSON (instead of N3) the results will be converted into a dict, which you can then serialize however you want. If you just want to save the response, you can access the `response` property of the object returned by SPARQLWrapper.query.

Comment: What libraries are you use. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: @amirouche I updated my code

Comment: There is an error in the SPARQL query there is no need to wrap the entity with angle brackets `<>`. Also the wikidata endpoint doesn't support N3, it seems like it only support xml sparql-results and json but not json-ld.

Comment: Also what the purpose of your program exactly? You want to convert the N3 to N3? it doesn't make sens?

Comment: Can you write an answer about the SPARQL error so that I can mark it as an answer and you can get the points! I haven't noticed the SPARQL error at all. I just wanted to serialize the output, but RDFLib can only serialize it if it's an RDF serialization (RDF, N3, N-Triples, Turtle, etc).

Comment: It looks like only JSON is supported. That doesn't help us too much in terms of saving the results of the queries in an RDF format. However the alternative is to construct the queries as you would construct them when sending them via cURL. That way it works OK. Thanks for help!